# Manually Created Flavor Resources Not Building Correctly

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-flavors

I have a strange question.  I already figured out a solution to the problem, but i am curious on WHY it did not work when i manually tried create a flavor's assets folders.

So i wanted to add a new Flavor to an existing Android project that already included a few flavors. I went into the *app level build.gradle* file and added on a new flavor. In this example i am adding `Flavor_Two`:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.fancyapp.APP_NAME"
}
flavorDimensions "client"
productFlavors {
    Flavor_One {
        applicationId 'com.fancyapp.one'
        dimension "client"
    }
    Flavor_Two {
        applicationId 'com.fancyapp.two'
        dimension "client"
    }
}
```

I then went manually into my file explorer and created the assets folders & files:
`"/app/src/Flavor_Two/res/values/strings.xml"`
`"/app/src/Flavor_Two/res/mimap-hdpi/icon.png"`

When building the flavor, it does not use the Flavor_Two assets, but instead uses the default values, which is `com.fancyapp.APP_NAME` not `com.fancyapp.two`. The app crashes because it is also looking for a local database by the *PackageName* which should be `com.fancyapp.two` but instead finds `com.fancyapp.APP_NAME`.

I figured out if i deleted my manually created folder `Flavor_Two` and instead went through Android Studio's menu `"File > New > Android Resource Directory"` and selected my `Flavor_Two` as the `Source Set` and `Values` as the `Resource Type`, that created the `"/app/src/Flavor_Two/res/values"` folder and parent folders. It was the same folder names as i had manually made before. I then copied over the `strings.xml` file. I only had to make the initial folders through Android Studio's menu; i could copy over the "mimap-hdpi" folder i had previously used and the flavor would build correctly.

My question is this:
*WHY wouldn't Android Studio and Gradle not see my manually made folders, and WHAT else does making the folder through the menu do that i would need to do if i wanted to manually do everything in the future.*

Thanks if anyone has any insights.

---

Android Studio Version: 3.1.3
Gradle Build Version: 3.1.3
Buildtools Version: 27.0.3
Compiled SDK Version: 23
OS: Windows 10

Comment: I am using a freshly updated version of Android Studio 3.x and having the same issue as the poster. Manually created folders and files are not recognized in the build process. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 2):

That should have worked fine.  Probably just a sync issue.  Try making the folder manually and then hitting the 'Sync with File System' and then 'Sync Project with Gradle Files' toolbar icons in Android Studio after manually making the directory.  The are next to the save icon.